# EvoPdf and FIPS

Tags: pdf, evopdf

I'm using evo pdf and asp application was hosted on windows server 2016.

I'm not able to generate a report getting FIPS error:
I tried turning of the fips that cannot able to contact the windows server 2016 hosted sql server.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with FIPS Validated Cryptographic Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104331/problem-with-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms)

Comment: I tried turning off the fips but didn’t work.